# PGN viewer menu is hidden behind the navigation bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, pgn-viewer

When you click the arrow pointing down on the top right of the PGN viewer, the menu appears in the top left of the screen. However, only a part of it appears:

[image: Screenshot of the faulty menu]

This is very confusing. What everyone would understand (without a close look) is that "Copy Position" and "Copy Start Position" are the only available options. Now, I have removed the navigation bar (using Chrome dev tools):

[image]

A new option appears!

## Solution:

For the menu (`div.modal.context-menu`), change `top:10px` to any value greater than 50px (`top:75px` looks good). Here is a screenshot with `top:75px` applied:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tweaked the styling and the positioning of the menu (and the copy/paste modals), so they should show up in a more reasonable location now.

I was aiming for showing both right by the arrow, but for some reason that's not quite happening in production the same way I had it locally. I'll try to carve out some more time to get it in shape, but in the meantime... it should at least be more visible and usable.

Please let me know if you run into any other issues with the controls.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts!